# Problem in Asp.Net web Application Administration for SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net

When I click the security tab in Asp.Net Web Application Administration the ASPNETDB.MDF database is not created.

I am using SQL Server 2005 and MS Visual Studio 2008.

What must I do to solve the problem

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With default settings when you click the Website admin tool it will try using the settings for membership provider from machine.config, if you haven't set anything in your web.confing. Those settings expects Sql Express instance on your machine. That could be one of the reason.
So as mentioned by Chris you will need to use aspnet_regsql.exe to install membership schema to your database.
But that alone won't suffice. You will have to modify your connection string to point to your new membership database.

Check this: [Using Sql Server 2005 with membership](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx)

If you already have Sql Express on your machine, then there might be something else may be in your web.config that has changed and causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

Create the database manually using aspnet_regsql.exe:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx

(Short version)

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A mr
```